# Why isn't my link being followed in bootstrap nav bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need some help modifying some bootstap mark up. I have a standard nav bar. My problem is that when I click on the top most `li` it doesn't follow the link. If I click on any of the sub `li` they work perfectly.

a short snippet of what my code looks like for one of the links:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse navHeaderCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
              <li><a><img src="images/home.png" alt="home"></a></li>
              <li class="dropdown"><a href="service.html" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Link&nbsp;<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a>Sub-Link 1</a></li>
                  <li><a>Sub-Link 1</a></li>
                  <li><a>Sub-Link 1</a></li>
                  <li><a>Sub-Link 1</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
```

If I click on the `Link` item it doesn't navigate to the `service.html` page? I've thought of using js to set it's href but that forces me to hard code the link and when all is done this page and the links are going to be generated via a CMS. Is there a way for me to enable the link on the page?

For those asking I have the sub links set to show on hover instead of click

Comment: You can't modify single bit of html there ?  If you can just remove data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"  .. or remove them using jQuery should do it too.

Comment: The purpose of `data-toggle="dropdown" ` is to toggle the dropdown, not navigation. What is the point of showing a dropdown only to navigate away from page?

Comment: @ ZimSystem Yes, I see that now, thank you. If you put your answer to remove the data-toggle = "dropdown" in I'll check it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Bootstrap's dropdown class will allow you to create a link on the dropdown title. You might want to create another navigation for service.html or add it in the dropdown list